# Can't call Invoke

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, 2d-games

I've been struggling with this problem for hours and still can't figure it out so can anyone help me with this?

My invoke method is not doing anything. here's my code:

```
void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(robot.transform.position, player.transform.position, speed);
         if(hitNum <= 0){
            Invoke(nameof(Effects), 2.0f);
        }
       
    }

// Damage Function

 public void Damage(float damage){
        hitNum -= damage;
        scr.SetHealth(hitNum,max);
        
       
    }

// Particle System

 public void Effects(){
    
         foreach (var fireworks in fireworks)
        {
            fireworks.Play(); 
         
        }

}
```

I'm trying to add some particles after player defeats the robot, but it's not working

Comment: Try removing the condition to see if it works.

Comment: Also, you should not call Invoke at every Updata, this can sometimes lead to crashing the editor.

Comment: I tried and it works without condition

Comment: But I can't call it in Start method, I want it to appear after 2 seconds when player defeats the enemy

Comment: Then you should consider using events. [Unity Events](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OuZrhykVytg&pp=ygUMdW5pdHkgZXZlbnRz). The reason income won't work is that update runs every frame, and in that every frame Invoke will be called after every 2 seconds, so even when the enemy dies, the invoke will still be running and cause performance issues.

Comment: I watched about events and I think it's not exactly what I'm trying to achieve in my code

Answer (score 1):

The code you have provided looks correct. But it's hard to say without full script provided. Please, make sure to post your full script next time and also to explain your issue better, not just "it doesn't work"

- First make sure your code doesn't throw you any errors
- Make sure your `Time.timeScale` isn't set to zero (`print(Time.timeScale)`)
- Make sure that `hitNum <= 0` condition is true by printing it before `Invoke` method
- If it is true, then `Effects` method should be called in 2 seconds, make sure it's also called, though I don't see any reason for it not to be called
- Make sure `fireworks` collection isn't empty (if it's null, it will throw you an error)
- Make sure those `ParticleSystems` are in the scene and see if they are played
  That shouldn't be that hard to debug too. I hope that helped you a bit!

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but it doesn't help me. I mean I checked everything except the timescale. I don't get exactly what do you mean? do u mean time in invoke? besides that there are no errors and also fireworks is not empty, they are in the scene and I put them in public array.

Comment: hitnum condition is working and effects method is working too but invoke isn't, it starts immediately playing the effects and I want to wait for 2 seconds

Comment: Make sure it really starts 2 seconds after. Just print when condition is true and when `Effects` method is called. Also make sure to write `Time.timeScale` when condition is true. Please, google something if you don't know it. [`Time.timeScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html) is the scale at which timei passes. If it's normal value `1f`, it equals to real time and Invoke is called exactly in 2 seconds. But if it's e.g. `0.1f`, it's 10 times slower and `Invoke` is called in just `0.2` seconds. Please, make sure you have checked everything, it should work

Comment: Thanks, I solved this problem. Problem was that this script was written inside my enemy and not the player, so after enemy was defeated obviously it didn't work. And I also tried Time.timeScale but it's not exactly what I wanted. It just slows down entire game, not only effects.

Comment: Yes, your issue is quite obvious. I haven't said you that you have to change `Time.deltaTime`, I have said that you have to check if it's set to default value, because you could have changed it somewhere. Anyway, I don't know if you can change it if you won't know what it is. Just to make sure you check it.